# Ajax Post method not working !! Help me out

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp-classic

Below attached is my code that includes an ajax call with the inclusion of jquery library.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
 $.post("index4.asp",
 {
   name:"Donald Duck",
   city:"Duckburg"
 },
 function(data,status){
   alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
 });
 });
 });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the code for my 'index4.asp' file

```
<%
dim fname,city
fname=Request.Form("name")
city=Request.Form("city")
Response.Write("Dear " & fname & ". ")
Response.Write("Hope you live well in " & city & ".") 
 %>
```

My Output is an alert box with  the content

```
<%
 dim fname,city
 fname=Request.Form("name")
 city=Request.Form("city")
 Response.Write("Dear " & fname & ". ")
 Response.Write("Hope you live well in " & city & ".") 
  %> 
 with  status = success
```

instead the alert box has to be

```
  Dear DonaldDuck.Hope you live well in Duckburg.
   with status=success
```

Help me out!!I'm using Linux.

Comment: Where is the "index4.asp" file located? In a web server that can process ASP? Or, in your local file system?  From your output, it looks like your ASP is not getting executed.

Comment: Also, please specify the URL displayed on the address bar when you open the web page.  This will help us to know if your code is being served from Server or file system.

Answer (score 0):

One reason why this could happen is that you are not running your HTML page from server.

Easy way to find that out is, see the URL displayed in the address bar of the browser.  If it starts with "file://" then, you are doing it wrong.  It should start with "http://" for your current code to work.

Now, if the URL reads "http://" and then if you still get the error, then, the web server which you are running cannot run ASP.  Use a web server that can understand ASP instead.

If you do not have a ASP web server running, refer http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_install.asp to know how to do it.

Comment: vivek_ganesan my url looks something like 'http://127.0.0.1:8020/jquery/index3.html'

Comment: @user3777766 Then, you are running from web server.  But, what webserver are you using?

Comment: I'm running my code from  aptana studio3 .It's taking me on to the browser

Comment: @user3777766 Can you try to type just http://127.0.0.1:8020 in your browser and let me know if it prints any server name?

Comment: @user3777766 No, i meant, to just type 127.0.0.1:8020 in your browser address bar without "/jquery/index3.html" and press enter. See what it displays.

Comment: Though,I typed the URL suggested by you.It is getting directed to http webserver.

Comment: I'm gettting 'File / not found' message

Comment: @user3777766 Let me install aptana studio 3 in my computer and tell you.. gimme some time.

Comment: or else..can i try this through notepad++?

Comment: @user3777766 The web server that Aptana invokes does not support ASP.  If you got this ASP file from someone else, ask them how they run it and in what server.  They might help you in understanding which server they usually use to run it.

Comment: No i just got it from w3schools.com.so i really donot have any idea!

Comment: @user3777766 That explains it :) ASP, JSP, PHP, etc. are server-side programming languages that need to be run on web/application servers that can understand those languages.  The execution of the code happens in server.

Whereas, in case of client-side languages like HTML, Javascript, etc., execution happens in the browser.  So, if you really want to execute this example, you need a server that would run ASP.  Refer to http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_install.asp for doing this.

Comment: Imo directing people to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com) is poor choice as that site is often wrong or promotes bad practice.

Comment: Also for reference `127.0.0.1` is commonly used IPv4 loop-back address that is used to denote the [localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), in other words they are running the web server locally on their machine using TCP port `8020`.